# Is $\ell^p$ is closed in $c_0$ for $1 \le p < \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Is $\ell^p$ is closed in $c_0$ for $1 \le p < \infty$?

I think yes since if we have a sequence $(x_n^k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ of sequences for which for each $x_n$ holds that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p< \infty$ converging to some $(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$, then I would think that $\sum_{n =1}^\infty |y_n|^p < \infty$ also.

I don't quite know how to prove this. If $(x_n^k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is such a sequence in $\ell^p$ that it converges to $(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$, then is the convergence pointwise or uniform we're talking about here?

At least it should be pointwise that is $x_1^k \to y_1$, $x_2^k \to y_2, \dots$, when $k \to \infty$, but what are the conclusions that can be drawn from here?

Comment: To answer your question, what is the norm on $c_0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I think it should be the sup norm?

Comment: The space $\ell^p$ is dense in $c_0.$ It is not closed. Let $x^{(n)}_k={1\over \log (k+2)}$ for $1\le k\le n$ and $x^{(n)}_k=0$ for $k>n.$ Then $x^{(n)}\in \ell^p$ for any $p,$ but the limit in $c_0$ does not belong to $\ell^p.$

Comment: Is there some motivation for this wild logarithm appearing in the denominator? @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: The set of sequences with only finite number of non-zero terms is also a subset of $\ell^{p}$ which is dense in $c_0$.

Comment: Elements given in the example have finitely many nonzero terms. The reason for this particular example is that the limit does not belong to $\ell^p$ for all $p,$ not just one fixed $p.$ The shift of the  is to avoid dividing by $0.$ I could have taken $1/\log(n+1).$

Comment: I believe the harmonic series is a more evident counterexample. Indeed, take $p=1$ and consider the sequences $(x_k^{(n)})_{k\geq 1}$ such that for $k \leq n$ we put $x_k^{(n)} = 1/k$. Then, all these sequences are in $l^1$, but their limit is not. It is a well known fact that $\sum_{n\geq 1}1/n = \infty$.  Nevertheless $1/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.